# useTransition in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-spring

Why when I use react spring's `useTransition` all my elements are blank?

When I don't declare useTransition this is the result I get

[image]

this is when i declare useTransition

[image]

this is the error appearing in the console

[image]

here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring';
import '../scss/Tutorial.scss'

export default function TutorialPage() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  const hiddenTutorial = () => {
    document.querySelector('.tutorial').style.display = 'none';
  }

  const toggleBtn = () => {
    setShow(v => !v)
    setTimeout(() => setShow(v => !v), 500)
  }

  const transition = useTransition(show, {
    from: {x: 1, y: 2},
    enter: {x: 0, y: 0},
    leave: {}
  })

  return (
    <div className='tutorial'>
      {transition((style, item) => 
        item ? (<animated.div style={style} className='content-1'>
        <div className='content'>
          <div className='title-content'>
            MARVIC
          </div>
          <div className='main-content'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </div>
        </div>
      </animated.div>) : ''
      )}
      {transition((style, item) => 
        item ? (<animated.div className='content-2'>
        <div className='content2'>
          <div className='title-content'>
            Welcome
          </div>
          <div className='main-content'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <div className='btn'>
            <button className='btn-previous' onClick={toggleBtn}>Previous</button>
            <button className='btn-next' onClick={toggleBtn}>Next</button>
            <button className='btn-skip' onClick={hiddenTutorial}>Skip</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </animated.div>) : ''
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: hi Thịnh, why do you need to check `item ?`? What if when you remove that condition?

Comment: I just declared an empty useTransition (no need to use it) and it returned such a blank page!

Answer (score 1):

from Reactjs 18, you have to first call createRoot() then call render(). Otherwise, some new features in 18 can't be used

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).